# ServiceStack RazorRockstars Example - Reserved Route?

Tags: servicestack

I have an issue with the RazorRockstars example. I have renamed the main route (`/rockstars`) on the `Rockstars` request class to `/properties` and now it no longer loads. It appears `/properties` route is reserved. Is this the case? I wish to use this route in my application.

Works:

```cs
[Route("/rockstars")]
[Route("/rockstars/{Id}")]
[Route("/rockstars/aged/{Age}")]
public class Rockstars
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Works:

```cs
[Route("/blahblahblah")]
[Route("/blahblahblah/{Id}")]
[Route("/blahblahblah/aged/{Age}")]
public class Rockstars
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Does not work:

```cs
[Route("/properties")]
[Route("/properties/{Id}")]
[Route("/properties/aged/{Age}")]
public class Rockstars
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `/properties` doesn't work in development because it matches a folder in your root directory (which hi-jacks the request), i.e. in this case VS.NET's `Properties/` folder it uses to hold your projects `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

It will work after you rename the `Properties` folder to something else, or once you deploy since deployment builds doesn't include the `Properties` folder.

Comment: @mythz Is there a way to find that out or did you just know form your own experience?

Comment: @tobsen there's no magical or reserved Route keywords that you can't use in ServiceStack. If a Route keyword doesn't work as expected, it's because you have a conflicting folder with the same name.